# Magento sort by price: sort by final price instead of price

Tags: attributes, magento-1, sorting

**Magento sort by price: sort by final price instead of price:**

I want to **`sort by price`** filter to sort by final price of product instead of just price. For product I have price 10 but special price is 100 , so when user sort product by price, sorting looks wrong.

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

#### The Background:

As @Shawn Abramson mentioned, this is not possible without an additional mechanism.

The sorting must be specified in the first query (`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract:1045`), as this is the result set that future queries add data to. I believe you need to always include a separate join to the price index table. This is unfortunate, as it is more records to search/load, reducing performance. That trade-off is up to you and your client.

#### The Mechanism:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_collection');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->setPageSize(10);
$products->setCurPage(1);

$products->joinTable(
    ['price_table' => Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/resource')->getTable('catalog/product_index_price')],
    'entity_id = entity_id',
    [ 'price', 'final_price' ],
    [
        'customer_group_id' => 0,
        'website_id' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
    ]
);
$products->getSelect()->order('price_table.final_price DESC');
```

#### The Explanation:

The first four lines are whatever your standard collection filtering code is. Thereafter there are two functions:

1. `$products->joinTable()`: this function joins the `catalog/product_index_price` table and retrieve the two columns for reference. **Please Note**: you need specify the `customer_group_id` and the `website_id` unless these placeholder values work for you.
2. `$products->getSelect()->order()`: this function performs the order process.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrProductIds is Array of product ids.

$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $arrProductIds))
                ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC')
                ->addAttributeToSort('finalprice','DESC')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('finalprice');

        foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
            echo $product->getname();
            echo $product->getfinalprice().'  ';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Final price is not an actual attribute so some special logic would need to be created. You can, however, sort by special_price attribute.